# Prototype constructor for functions and objects

Tags: javascript, prototype

So I have been doing a lot of reading about the prototype and I get it for the most part, I mean, I get the following.

```
var Animal = function(species) {
    this.species = species;
};
Animal.prototype.getSpecies = function() {
    return this.species;
}
var myDog = new Animal("Anderson");    
alert(myDog.getSpecies());
```

I even understand that I could create a new species and set the prototype to Animal and then be able to call getSpecies(). Yeah!

What confuses me is this:

```
var Person = function(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName= firstName;
    this.lastName= lastName
};

var meToo = { fName: "ken", lName: "N" };
alert(meToo.constructor.prototype);  // [object Object]
alert(Person.constructor.prototype); // function Empty(){}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r0k3t/s8Sx7/9/

I was trying to find something that explains why the prototype for Person is function() {}? I thought it would be set to the global object, 'this' (which in this case is window). Also - why can't I enumerate the properties of it? Reading [this](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/) would suggest that I could use constructor.prototype to retrieve the object which I thought would be 'window' and then just enumerate the properties.

So clearly I am missing something - thanks!

Comment: try  console.log(meToo.constructor.prototype)

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle using logging http://jsfiddle.net/r0k3t/s8Sx7/14/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype for `Person` objects, is just `Person.prototype`. Not `Person.constructor.prototype`, which is very different:

`Person.constructor`, is the `Function` function, which constructs all functions. Because `Person` is a function, its `.constructor` is `Function`.

The prototype of `Function` objects (all functions), is just `Function.prototype`. So, `Person.constructor.prototype === Function.prototype`.

The constructor of plain objects is the `Object` function. The prototype of all plain objects is `Object.prototype`, which is an `"[object Object]"` (Prefer `console.dir` over `alert`, to see more).

By plain object, I mean anything created with `{}` or `new Object()`

Comment: So why would Angus Croll state "In addition all browsers except IE support the non-standard accessor __proto__. Failing that we can ask the object’s constructor for its prototype property." it makes it sound like Object.getPrototypeOf(myThing) will return the same thing as myThing.constructor.prototype? I mean, it makes some sense what you said but clearly I am still missing something. Hmm?

Comment: @Kenn yes, provided that constructor property is not meddled with: `myThing.__proto__ === Object.getPrototypeOf(myThing) === myThing.constructor.prototype`

Comment: @Kenn and if you create a new Person object. `var person = new Person()`, then same applies: `person.__proto__ === Object.getPrototypeOf(person) === person.constructor.prototype` Note that I am referring to lowercase `person.constructor`, not `Person.constructor`

Comment: So I just saw this - http://omgmattking.blogspot.com/2012/11/on-prototypes-inheritance-and-this-in.html I completely missed this "Since myObject is just a plain old object at the top of the Prototype chain, it has nowhere else to look for methods" I was under the impression that everything got assigned something to it's prototype even if it was the global object. Don't ask me where I got that from. With that said. I would label Angus Croll's article "confusing" or at least not for beginners to the concept.

Comment: @Kenn What Angus Croll means is, if you have `var person = new Person()`, then `person.__proto__ === Person.prototype`. `Person` is the constructor of `person` (so `person.constructor.prototype === Person.prototype`). On your jsfiddle you asked for `Person.constructor.prototype`, which is the `Function` function as Esailija explained.